# How do I block the user closing my app via the menu key?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

Is there some way, with Delphi, to block Menu Key on android so that the app can't be closed or is there some way prevent the user from closing the application?

Comment: Seriously? Because the back button can with "vkHardwareBack",they really don't have anything with home button? D:

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand. There must **ALWAYS** be a way of closing the app. Being incapable of closing the app would either be a bug, or else your app is Malware. Your goal should never be to prevent people from being able to use their phone...

Comment: I understand you, for now i just want to test how much Delphi can handle with Android, like activate GPS, block some buttons, it's just for test :)